# Fixing a Notepad++ curly brace issue I'm having

Tags: notepad++

I am having an issue (probably an option somewhere) with my Notepad++ installation whereby whenever I type a curly brace, it does not close itself automatically. Basically, what I would want is as soon as I open a curly brace, it auto-closes and I can resume typing within them (like most other text editors or IDEs).

I've looked into the issue and it seems not many people have had this problem but rather problems related to indentation and what not. For the record, I did not change any configuration settings.

If there's anybody that has had a similar issue with Notepad++ or might simply know the fix: greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To autocomplete the braces goto settings->preferences->auto-complete and chck all the check boxes and click on ok, after then your a

Answer (score 0):

I believe the option to turn this feature on and off is located under the TextFX menu

TextFx > TextFX Settings > +Autoclose {([Brace

Try toggling this option and see if that sorts it

Comment: Thanks Michael, that seemed to fix the issue however is there a way to just have it auto-complete for curly braces and not parenthese? Also, if you would know how to indent the cursor after pressing enter in between the curly braces, that'd be great. Thanks.

Comment: This should also work for curly braces, i found that it only worked for curly braces after i had saved the document i.e. it wouldn't work on a new unsaved document.

Answer (score 0):

Go to TextFX -> TextFX Settings -> +Autoclose {([Brace.

Answer (score -1):

Try [xbrackets lite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/XBrackets%20Lite/) plugin for notepad++.